# Django, React encountered static file 404 error. Is there any solution?

Tags: reactjs, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, react-redux

In Dango, index.html of React is successfully displayed, but it is not rendered and only white blank pages are displayed.

Below are my settings.

/etc/nginx/sites-available/mystar.conf:

[image]

django setting:

[image]

[image]

dir tree:
[image]

site error:

[image]

React is shown by setting the build folder from the template of Janggo.

How can I solve the above error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and add the react "build" folder to INSTALLED_APPS in the settings.py file.

Comment: I solved it in a different way. Thank you for your answer.